# I can not select a single child object from a parent object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

Probably I accidentally clicked on something, so it can be something very simple. But suddenly I can not select any child objects. When I click on a child object, the entire parent object is automatically selected.

I have a stadium, divided into sections, rows, seats etc. When I select a single seat, the entire parent object (the stadium) is immediately selected. Previously this was never the case, this is suddenly since yesterday.

Does anyone know what I could have clicked on accidentally? Thanks!

Video here: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2dl3nlc/9

It depends on the (parent) object. Because I **can** select one child of the parent goal, but I **can't** select one child of the parent grandstand, then the whole grandstand is selected... You can't see it because it are dark colors, but the grandstand contains of multiple chairs (childs)

Comment: Can you upload video about this issue?

Comment: Added the video! And a small description

Comment: I can't see it. Upload the gif to imgur

Comment: Why u dont select the parent in the treeview ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you clicked the layer locks. have a look.

[image]

if you lock a layer out, objects belongs to that layer will be not selectable from the editor scene view.